# "eig_cpu" not implemented for 'Long' in torch.eig(x)

Tags: google-colaboratory, torch

import torch
X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1]])
e, v = torch.eig(X, eigenvectors=True)
v
**********output***************
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
1 import torch
2 X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1]])
----> 3 e, v = torch.eig(X, eigenvectors=True)
4 v

RuntimeError: "eig_cpu" not implemented for 'Long'

Answer (score 0):

I identified that at least a float value in the **tensor** is necessary to clear up this error
X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1.0]])

X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1]])

try adding a decimal ....so I have:

```
import torch
X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1.0]])
e, v = torch.eig(X, eigenvectors=True)
```

output  :

```
tensor([[ 0.7512,  0.6106, -0.3430],
        [ 0.6229, -0.7733,  0.2476],
        [ 0.2185, -0.1710,  0.9061]])
```

without decimal :
import torch
X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1]])
e, v = torch.eig(X, eigenvectors=True)
v
output with errors when tensor  does not have a single float value elem :
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
1 import torch
2 X = torch.tensor ([[25, 2, 9], [5, 25, -5], [3, 7, -1]])
----> 3 e, v = torch.eig(X, eigenvectors=True)
4 v

RuntimeError: "eig_cpu" not implemented for 'Long'